# finite sets in a metric space

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Is it possible to describe every finite set in a metric space as closed, even though empty set is open, and in discrete metric the finite subset is open?
For every subset of a metric space, its closure being the set of all $a \in M$ such that the intersection of the subset and $B[a;e]$ is finite for any $e>0$.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Always remember that a set may be both closed and open, or it may be neither.

Comment: Yes, it is fine. A closed set can be open, nothing forbids that.

Comment: Yes, every finite subset of a metric space is closed. This is completely independent of whether any of them are also open: a set can be both.

Comment: @Bob : yes, every finite set in a metric space is closed.  It is not just "possible to describe" it as closed, it actually is closed.  You should avoid weasel words when writing, talking, or asking about mathematics.  However, sometimes a closed set is also open, as all the previous comments note.

Comment: I understand it can be both, I was just wondering whether it has to be strictly closed, when we say every/any is. I guess, not. Thanks.

Comment: @Bob : I'm not sure what you mean by "strictly closed".  Either a set is closed or it isn't.  By the way, using the discrete metric, all sets are open, not just finite sets.

Comment: "strictly" meaning only closed and not open. I was comparing finite, so I said finite in discrete. I realize that they are all clopen

Comment: As an old teacher of mine once said: sets are not doors, they can be open and closed at the same time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to describe every finite set in a metric space as closed

Yes: every finite set in a metric space is closed. (As said in comments).

> For every subset of a metric space, its closure being the set of all $a\in M$ such that the intersection of the subset and $B[a;\epsilon]$ is finite for any $\epsilon >0$.

This is not what the closure of a set means. Its definition is similar to the above, but the intersection with $B[a;\epsilon]$ must be **nonempty**, not *finite*.

In fact, the property you stated describes the set of all isolated points of the given subset.